# Python special characters + line break

Tags: python, regex, line, break

I have a .sav file which contains geo-coordinates and adresses which kinda looks like this (just like the whole text file is full of it and there are no line-breaks)

```
"*g    !  –Ѓ›M& 1дj шTњM. 1д‚ »Ѓ›M2 1dѓ ЅЃ›M> 1dШ ОЃ›M? 1ди аЃ›M@ 1й гЃ›Mu 1д‚ є      0000008e92ec333e003e19ec2222 1 1 1 1 1   C I T Y N A M E *"
```

So I want to make a little script which deletes the special characters like in the example above the "*Ѓ›M& 1дj шTњM*" and starts a new line with every coordinate, which would look like this:

```
00000452324235234132123 1 1 1 1 1 C i t y S t r e e t n a m e 46A
```

The only thing I managed to make was to open the text file and read line-by-line:

```
import re
a = "Filepath.txt"  
b = re.compile('[^\sa-zA-Z0-9]\S*')
 with open (a) as d:
    while True:
        e = d.read()
        if e:
            re.sub(b, "",e)
        if not e:
            break
    print (e)
```

Is there anybody who could help me out on this issue? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why `lx` at the first got removed?

Comment: That trash at the front looks like binary data, and perhaps `CityStreetname` is UTF-16? Perhaps you can give us a little more information about this data format?

Comment: Well for the trash up front , I will add a real example tomorrow since the signs I used above are just dummy's. The signs that appear in my real file look like some weird ASCII Signs

Comment: The proper solution is to figure out the binary format and write (or borrow) a parser for it. The "trash" is not trash, and could coincidentally contain what looks like valid text. How do you tell whether `12` is part of the binary structure, or part of the address?

Comment: well, the address follows the pattern 5-digit Zip code, City, Street, 2-3 digit house number, that way I can figure out whether it is part of the address or not ..

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a single `re.sub` function.

```
>>> s = "*ä-#+ölx 00000452324235234132123 xasf 1 1 1 1 1 C i t y S t r e e t n a m e ---..-.yxaewr 46A*"
>>> re.sub(r'[^\sa-zA-Z0-9]\S*', r'', s).strip()
'00000452324235234132123 xasf 1 1 1 1 1 C i t y S t r e e t n a m e  46A'
```

`[^\sa-zA-Z0-9]` matches all the non-word characters except space and the following `\S*` matches the following zero or more space characters. So it would remove all the characters following the mentioned non-word characters.

Comment: I kind of got it working using a the re.sub function, so I removed all characters which are not A-Z and 0-9 (I will update the code above as soon as I get back to work tomorrow) but now I have the problem of how to separate the lines. I have all the data written in 3 extra long lines but don't really know how to separate them.

Comment: I updated the data in my question above, including the real non-word characters and the new code.

Comment: `and starts a new line with every coordinate, which would look like this:` ? where is the newline character present in your expected output?

Comment: The new line is supposed to start with every coordinate. After I rund the code above my output looks like this "0000008e92ec333e003e19ec2222 1 1 1 1 1   C I T Y N A M E  0000008e92ec333e003e003e19ec2222 1 1 1 1 C I T Y N A M E "  so I want it to start a new line after the E of CITYNAME or before the first 0 of the new coordinate